# Integral involving Bessel function of the first kind with trigonometric argument

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

I need to solve the following integral:

$I_1 = \int_0^{2\pi} d \varphi \ \cos^m(\varphi) \frac{J_4\left(A\sqrt{a^2+b^2+2ab \cos \varphi}\right)}{a^2+b^2+2ab \cos \varphi}$
with $m$ positive integer and $a$, $b$ and $A$ positive real.

Looking through Gradshteyn (7th ed.) the closest one I could find was 6.684.1. (which sadly is not very close...).

Are you aware/have intuition of wheather there might be an analytic solution to/simpler form of $I_1$?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try Graf's addition theorem for Bessel functions?

Comment: Yes, however I am not sure if it yields a 'simpler' form due to the infinite sum in there. As an application note, $I_1$ is the innermost integral of an expression that involves a bunch of more Bessel functions.

Comment: Can you start a new question with the whole expression that you want to simplify?

Comment: A full simplification will most likely be not possible as there is a numeric function coupling all the other integrals. Getting rid of the innermost one in this question would already help a lot.

Comment: Using the recurrence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Recurrence_relations one can reduce $\frac{J_4(x)}{x^2}$ to a finite sum of Bessel functions. Then use Graf's theorem for every Bessel function in this sum. Graf's series is a Fourier series depending on angle $\phi$. Since Fourier series of $\cos^m\phi$ is a finite sum, this  integral will be a finite sum of Bessel functions.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I am not sure, however, how one could use the orthogonality of the cosines for the form of Graf's Theorem (i.e. given in 10.23.7 in https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.23) as it links two dependent angles of the triangle.